# Using Ganache UI: Is there a way to find the names of the smart contracts?

Tags: ganache

I realize this might be a limitation of Ethereum blockchain itself, but I thought that once I migrated a contract to Ganache I would be able to see the names, methods and method arguments of the contract using the Ganache UI. Is that wrong?